# Fixed vs. Random effects meta- regression

Tags: meta-analysis

how to understand the differences between fixed vs. random effects meta-regression? Not meta-analysis.

Comment: Difference between fixed and random effects?

Comment: Meta regression is a tool used in meta-analysis.